# Отношения в диаграммах классов

Tags: uml, диаграммы

Сильно запутался с отношениями в диаграммах классов. И чтобы "распутаться", помогите разобраться со следующим примером:

Пускай есть класс Авокадо. Оно содержит в себе Косточку. Что характерно, Авокадо без Косточки не может существовать, а косточка очень даже может. Есть Мешок ТОЛЬКО для Авокадо. В Мешке может быть сколько угодно Авокадо [0..*]. Есть Подгреб для Мешков, пускай вмещает он только 10 Мешков, ни больше и не меньше. Какие же отношения будут между нашими классами?

Что характерно, Косточке, наплевать в каком Авокадо она находится, так же и Авокадо наплевать в каком Мешке оно сидит. Да и Мешку всё равно в какой Погреб его сунули.

P.S. Пример придумывал сам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не самый лучший пример, во-первых, очевидно, что он подразумевает только описание разницы между композицией, агрегацией и ассоциацией. А во-вторых, исходя из описания все отношения являются композициями.

- *Ассоциация* — это отношение «я ссылаюсь на». Относительно слабая связь, когда ни один из объектов не может представляться владельцем другого. Обычно связь многие ко многим представляется им, но он вполне может представлять и любую другую связь в зависимости от логики поведение объектов.
- *Агрегация* и *Композиция* — это специфические виды ассоциации, выражающие отношение «я включаю». Ключевая разница между ними — кто контролирует время жизни включаемого объекта. Так при *агрегации* время жизни контролирует кто-то третий. А при *композиции* — непосредственно контейнер. Важная особенность в том, что если объект не исключён из контейнера до его уничтожения он уничтожается вместе с ним. Детали этого контроля остаются за кадром UML диаграм, так в C++ это может быть как полноценный член класса так и массив указателей, которые удаляются в деструкторе.

> Пускай есть класс Авокадо. Оно содержит в себе Косточку. Что характерно, Авокадо без Косточки не может существовать, а косточка очень даже может.

На самом деле мысли о том, что без чего может существовать вторичны и отвлекают от сути. Если мы вдруг решим, что Авокадо там больше не нужно и бросим его в печь, нам нужно будет, чтобы косточка автомагическим образом осталась лежать на полке? Вероятно нет, значит это *композиция*. Это не исключает того, что мы можем достать косточку и сохранить её на полке перед удалением или извлекать во время поедания, если это действительно необходимо.

> Есть Мешок ТОЛЬКО для Авокадо. В Мешке может быть сколько угодно Авокадо [0..*].

Опять, если бросить мешок в ту же топку все авокадо будут уничтожены. Так что это снова *композиция*.

> Есть Подгреб для Мешков, пускай вмещает он только 10 Мешков, ни больше и не меньше.

Пожар ⇒ всё сгорело ⇒ *композиция*.

#### Теперь немного расширю, пример, дабы проиллюстрировать другие отношения.

> У складов есть владельцы (кладовщики), при этом одним складом владеет только один человек.

Т.к. со скоропостижной кончиной владельца склад не самовоспламеняется, а при пожаре на складе владелец не умирает от сердечного приступа, то это уже не композиция, но при этом отношения кладовщик — склад подразумевают владение, так что это агрегация.

> Мешки не просто так появляются на складах, а их присылают фермеры, при этом один мешок происходит только от одного фермера и на мешке написано от кого, но любой фермер может работать со многими кладовщиками при этом у кладавщиков есть записи с кем они работали, а у фермеров с кем они.

Отношения фермер—мешок не подразумевают владение, так что являются ассоциацией один ко многим. Отношения кладавщик — фермер также являются ассоциацией, но уже многие ко многим, при этом т.к. списки есть и у фермеров и у кладовщиков, то это, то это двунаправленная ассоциация.

Итог:

[image: Диаграмма классов (Без методов выглядит куцо, но интерфейс мне выдумывать уже лень.)]

**Дисклеймер:** всё описанное выше — это моё видение и понимание данной темы, оно не претендует на абсолютное истинность, однако я старался сделать его как можно менее противоречивым. Я не призываю к поджогу продовольственных складов, а также к бессмысленному уничтожению авокадо, владельцев складов или фермеров.

Comment: то есть вполне данные о нашем Авокадо могут храниться в БД, а когда нужно положить его в мешок, мы воссоздаём Авокадо из БД и кладём его в мешок? И всё это композиция?

Comment: @koshachok не совсем понял вопрос... если UML  используется для проектирования БД, то композиция выражается внешним ключом с ON DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: Всё, я понял :) Спасибо за ответ, очень развёрнутый и полный у вас он получился.

Comment: И ещё маленький вопросик, отношения между Мешком/Аводадо/Косточкой и Кладовщиком - ассоциация?

Comment: нет, у них нет прямых отношений.

Comment: но если бы мы знали, что именно это авакадо принадлежит именно этому кладовщику?

Comment: С трудом представляю, зачем эта связь может понадобиться и что будет обозначать, так что мне сложно сказать в каких отношениях они будут состоять, но я бы сказал ассоциация...